# Change the date if the condition is met (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

How could I check if the cancellation of the document (row 1 in the Table, BUSINESS_STAE = Canceled or BUSINESS_STAE = CancelledInFirstNDays) happened in the month before the last active row (row 2 in the Table, BUSINESS_STAE = Active) using REPORTED_DATE?
If it happened, I should equalize the months of those two dates (in this case both should have a date: 2022-06)

Database table (fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=edc0ed9f5855ad847e8fab04aaec4e6a):

```
CREATE TABLE ImplPolicy
    ([POLICY_KEY] decimal, [LOAD_DATE] datetime2, [REPORTED_DATE] datetime2, [BUSINESS_STATE] varchar(57), [OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT] decimal(15,2), [PREMIUM_BASE] decimal(15,2), [INSURANCE_PREMIUM] decimal(15,2), [CREDIT_INITIAL_VALUE] decimal(15,2), [LOAN_INSTALMENT_AMOUNT] decimal(15,2), [CURRENCY_CODE] varchar(3))
;

INSERT ImplPolicy
    ([POLICY_KEY], [LOAD_DATE], [REPORTED_DATE], [BUSINESS_STATE], [OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT], [PREMIUM_BASE], [INSURANCE_PREMIUM], [CREDIT_INITIAL_VALUE], [LOAN_INSTALMENT_AMOUNT], [CURRENCY_CODE])
VALUES
    ('2234511332', '2022-06-28 13:10:23.5000000', '2022-05-01 00:00:00.0000000', 'Cancelled', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '1000.00', '0.00', 'EUR'),
    ('2234511332', '2022-06-28 12:57:18.8066667', '2022-06-28 00:00:00.0000000', 'Active', '900.00', '900.00', '4.50', '1000.00', '42.60', 'EUR'),
    ('2234511332', '2022-06-28 12:56:50.4966667', '2022-05-31 00:00:00.0000000', 'Active', '920.00', '920.00', '4.60', '1000.00', '42.60', 'EUR')
;
```

Table:

|  | POLICY KEY | LOAD_DATE | REPORTED_DATE | BUSINESS_STATE | OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT | PREMIUM BASE | INSURANCE PREMIUM | CREDIT_INITIAL_VALUE | LOAN_INSTALMENT_AMOUNT | CURRENCY_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2234511332 | 2022-06-28 13:10:23.5000000 | 2022-05-01 00:00:00.0000000 | Cancelled | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 1000.00 | 0.00 | EUR |
| 2 | 2234511332 | 2022-06-28 12:57:18.8066667 | 2022-06-28 00:00:00.0000000 | Active | 900.00 | 900.00 | 4.50 | 1000.00 | 42.60 | EUR |
| 3 | 2234511332 | 2022-06-28 12:56:50.4966667 | 2022-05-31 00:00:00.0000000 | Active | 920.00 | 920.00 | 4.60 | 1000.00 | 42.60 | EUR |

Desired Output:

|  | POLICY KEY | LOAD_DATE | REPORTED_DATE | BUSINESS_STATE | OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT | PREMIUM BASE | INSURANCE PREMIUM | CREDIT_INITIAL_VALUE | LOAN_INSTALMENT_AMOUNT | CURRENCY_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2234511332 | 2022-06-28 13:10:23.5000000 | 2022-**06**-01 00:00:00.0000000 | Cancelled | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 1000.00 | 0.00 | EUR |
| 2 | 2234511332 | 2022-06-28 12:57:18.8066667 | 2022-06-28 00:00:00.0000000 | Active | 900.00 | 900.00 | 4.50 | 1000.00 | 42.60 | EUR |
| 3 | 2234511332 | 2022-06-28 12:56:50.4966667 | 2022-05-31 00:00:00.0000000 | Active | 920.00 | 920.00 | 4.60 | 1000.00 | 42.60 | EUR |

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    implPolicy.REPORTED_DATE,
    implPolicy.BUSINESS_STATE,
    implPolicy.CREDIT_INITIAL_VALUE,
    implPolicy.OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT,
    implPolicy.INSURANCE_PREMIUM,
    implPolicy.LOAN_INSTALMENT_AMOUNT,
    implPolicy.PREMIUM_BASE,
    implPolicy.PREMIUM_RATE,
    premiumSat.CURRENCY_CODE,
FROM
    POLICY_HUB policyHub
    INNER JOIN POLICY_SAT_LATEST policySat ON policySat.POLICY_HKEY = policyHub.POLICY_HKEY
    INNER JOIN IMPL.POLICY_SAT implPolicy ON implPolicy.POLICY_HKEY = policyHub.POLICY_HKEY
    INNER JOIN ITEM_LINK itemLink ON policyHub.POLICY_HKEY = itemLink.POLICY_HKEY
    INNER JOIN ITEM_SAT itemSat ON itemLink.ITEM_HKEY = itemSat.ITEM_HKEY
    INNER JOIN PREMIUM_SAT premiumSat ON itemLink.ITEM_HKEY = premiumSat.PREMIUM_HKEY
WHERE
    policyHub.DOCUMENT_NUMBER = '111' AND
    implPolicy.LOAD_DATE = (SELECT MAX(implPolicyCheck.LOAD_DATE) FROM IMPL.POLICY_SAT implPolicyCheck WHERE implPolicy.POLICY_HKEY = implPolicyCheck.POLICY_HKEY AND FORMAT(implPolicy.REPORTED_DATE, 'yyyyMM') = FORMAT(implPolicyCheck.REPORTED_DATE, 'yyyyMM')) AND
    premiumSat.LOAD_DATE = implPolicy.LOAD_DATE AND
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, implPolicy.REPORTED_DATE), 0) BETWEEN
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, cast('2021-06-01T00:00:00' AS DATE)), 0) AND
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, cast('2022-06-30T00:00:00' AS DATE)), 0)
```

Comment: to be honest i can't see any difference between your inserted data and your wanted result table

Comment: Hi @nbk. This is not the desired table. It is the same table as this one created in fiddle.

Comment: Please show your **desired** output. Something like this perhaps? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ecc4c86ea84b05ce7740b66fd3bd79b0

Comment: please change it to the wanted result, that would maybe somewhat easier to understand

Comment: I added what the output should look like. It would be good to check that before the WHERE statement in the attached query.

Comment: Do you want to modify that row or just select all of them with that result?

Comment: Just to modify that row if the condition is met. Then the code in the WHERE statement would be adjusted to the desired scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a joined update, taking only the first row that is `active`

```sql
UPDATE cancelled
SET REPORTED_DATE = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, cancelled.REPORTED_DATE, active.REPORTED_DATE), cancelled.REPORTED_DATE)
FROM ImplPolicy cancelled
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1) active.REPORTED_DATE
    FROM ImplPolicy active
    WHERE active.POLICY_KEY = cancelled.POLICY_KEY
      AND active.BUSINESS_STATE = 'Active'
    ORDER BY
      active.REPORTED_DATE DESC
) active
WHERE cancelled.BUSINESS_STATE IN ('Cancelled','CancelledInFirstNDays')
  AND EOMONTH(cancelled.REPORTED_DATE) < EOMONTH(active.REPORTED_DATE);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1d41b752bfb3f67ca326c36c5166cdb7)

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this by using INNER JOIN, since I have to join one table to the **ImplPolicy** table, in order for this to work properly?

Comment: Yes you can use a pre-grouped join https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d1eabbeda8dc0ebc238bba87586f619c

Comment: Thank you, it really helps. I'm just wondering if there is a way to change the data in the table only momentarily, until we get the desired data? Then to return to the value that was before the comparison.

Comment: Sounds like you actually *don't* want to change the data you just want to select those results (which is what I asked you to start with). Yes of course you can do that https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3b63bc8470538d966b704ebb2936a655